# How to prove a language about futuristic events (uncertain facts) is decidable or not?

Tags: computer-science, computability

I get some weird questions about the decidability of a language that focuses on futuristic events (uncertain facts).
It is framed like this:

We deﬁne the following language:

```
L = {d, t| The temperature of the dth day in 2022 is t degree Celcius}.
```

How to prove or disprove this language is decidable? My intuition is that it is undecidable, but I find it hard to reduce $A_{TM}$ to it or find a direct proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important thing to keep in mind is that we may be able to prove that something is decidable even if we can't figure out precisely how to decide it. For example, each of the following sets is decidable:

- $X=\{0\}$ iff alien life exists and $X=\{1\}$ otherwise.

  - Why? Well, there are two possibilities for what $X$ could be, and each is decidable. We don't (yet) know *which* one is right, but we can say for sure that $X$ is decidable.
- $Y=$ The set of $n$ such that there is a block of at least $n$ many consecutive $7$s in the decimal expansion of $\pi$.

  - Why? Well, note that $Y$ is closed downwards: if $n\in Y$ and $m<n$ then $m\in Y$. So $Y$ is an initial segment of $\mathbb{N}$ *(possibly all of $\mathbb{N}$ itself - indeed, this is conjectured to be the case)*, and all of those are decidable.

Now let's look at your set. Certainly it's true that *we can't be sure right now* what algorithm decides it, even if it is decidable. However, it's also conceivable that it is decidable - maybe by sheer coincidence the pattern of temperatures in $2022$ happens to be really simple.

This suggests that there might be a "silly" reason that your set is decidable after all. Can you find something that indicates that that set is actually much simpler than it may first appear? *(HINT: how many days will there be in $2022$?)*

Comment: Thanks! I think now I get it, since my set is simply a finite set with 365 elements. However, I think I still feel a little bit unease about these un certain events. For the first problem, are you saying that the set contains either only 0 or 1, and we know how to decide both scenarios. And for the second example, we are saying that the set comprises natural numbers up to a mysterious number n, right? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @David Yup, that's right. Your set is a finite set, and every finite set is decidable; the fact that we don't know *how* it's decidable doesn't enter into it, all we need (and this applies to the other examples too) is that it is guaranteed to be one of a collection of sets each of which is decidable.

Comment: An arguably more satisfying notion can be gotten by bringing *provability* into the mix: we ask that an algorithm exist which provably (in some fixed theory) computes the set in question. But that's a distinct notion, and it's important to keep them separate.